# Bootstrap 4 column rows with buttons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've started to explore Bootstrap 4 and HTML5/CSS in general. I want to create a text area with two buttons on the side (centered horizontally to each other) :

[image]

The code I got is the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="sent_text" placeholder="Just write some text.."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-1" type="button">Send</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-1" type="button">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a row with 2 columns in it. The second column contains two rows.
Is that correct way to go?

Thanks

Comment: Content shouldn't be placed directly in `.row`. The `.row` is only used to contain columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better way of doing it with `justify-content-around d-flex flex-column` on the buttons column. There was no need of additional `row` element in the col-2 div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="sent_text" placeholder="Just write some text.."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 justify-content-around d-flex flex-column">
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button">Send</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="button">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### I think this method is way better. (:

- Use `col` for the `textarea` column so that it takes all the available space.
- Use `col-auto` for the buttons column so that it takes as much as space as it needs. And then use `d-flex flex-column` to change its direction.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="sent_text" placeholder="Just write some text.."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto d-flex flex-column">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-1" type="button">Send</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-1" type="button">Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place each button in a div with 'col-...' class.

[Bootstrap documentation about nesting elements in a row](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting)

Codepen with your example to show you the difference when you use 'col-...' class.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxBJag)

```
<div class="container mt-2">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="sent_text"
              placeholder="Just write some text.."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <div class="row">
             <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-1" type="button">Clear</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-1" type="button">Send in col</button>
          </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="row">
          <div class="offset-6 col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-1" type="button">Send centered using col</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also making the textarea none-reziable is good.Thus
Try this

```css
textarea.form-control{
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="sent_text" placeholder="Just write some text.."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-1" type="button">Send</button>
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-1" type="button">Clear</button>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```